# How can I print only pages I have selected by a checkbox to print in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, vba, macros, forms

I have a protected Word document with many macros.
It is approximately 45 pages long.

I want to add a checkbox on the top of each page and run a macro so that only the checked pages will be printed.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

An entirely different approach to get selected pages printed exists in Office, LibreOffice and most likely any other variant of these.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> opens the Print dialog.
Find the "(o) Pages" radio button, click it, then type the page numbers in the box beside it; as in:
`-2, 5-10, 17, 18, 20-` or similar.

By that you do not need to include special macros, and all the problems that comes with maintaining it.

Comment: the problem is that the page numbers keep changing, for instance if i have a particular form on a particular page lets say page 5, depending on what is entered on page 1-4, page 5 can sometimes be page 6, and trying to juggle the page numbers can be daunting